# Inexplicable Array assignment behavior in Java

Tags: java, arrays, intellij-idea, variable-assignment, skip

So here it goes. I've been building a piece of software for a bigger project, and right now, I am simply baffled by the way Java treats my code. I have absolutely no idea as to why Java behaves the way it does right here.

**It seems to skip part of my code, and assigns values to a different array than I expected when no according method is called.**

I have walked over this for a few hours now with the IntelliJ Debugger, inspecting everything ever so closely, but I have not found a single reason as to why things happen the way they do.

```
package com.whatareyoudoing.java;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * WHAT THE ACTUAL DUCK
 */
public class WTF {
    private int[] number;
    private int[] oldNumber;

    public WTF() {
        number = new int[1];
        oldNumber = new int[1];
    }

    public void putNumber(int c) {
        number[0] = c;
    }

    public void putOld() {
        if(Arrays.equals(oldNumber, number)) {
            System.out.println("Nothing to do!");
            return; //How on earth can they literally be the same?!
        }
        oldNumber = number;
    }

    public void doWTF() {
        putNumber(1); 
        putOld(); // Works.
        putNumber(2); // Expected Result: number = 2; oldNumber = 1 [NOPE] number = 2; oldNumber = 2
        putOld(); // [NOPE] Simply Skips with "Nothing to do"
        putNumber(3); // Same odd behaviour
        putOld(); // Aaaand skips again.
    }
}
```

**After calling putNumber the first time, using `putNumber` again *simultaneously* puts the value in both variables (`oldNumber` and `Number`) instead of only in `number[0]`**.

I continued to simplify my code as far as possible so this example is more hands-on. Obviously, the real example where I found this had arrays longer than a single element.

I also tested it with multidimensional arrays, as well as object arrays. No change in the behavior.

I am completely puzzled now and have absolutely no idea how to go on. If you can shed any light on this topic, please do so. I am more than confused.

Answer (score 6):

The following assignment statement:

```
    oldNumber = number;
```

makes `oldNumber` and `number` point to the same underlying array. Perhaps what you want is to make a copy:

```
    System.arraycopy(number, 0, oldNumber, 0, number.length);
```

See the [documentation for `System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) for full details.

Comment: What would be the correct way to assign the values of an array to another one then? Thank you for the rapid answer!

Answer (score 3):

This line isn't doing what you think it's doing.

```
oldNumber = number;
```

It isn't copying the contents of one array to another.  It is making the reference variable `oldNumber` refer to the same array object as `number` refers to.

```
oldNumber ----> [1]
number    -------^
```

So, any change through either variable writes through to the same array, and the change is visible through both references, which refer to the same array.

Then later you call `Arrays.equals` with references to the same array, so they are "equal".

You want to copy the number with this line instead:

```
oldNumber[0] = number[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

When you assign

```
oldNumber = number
```

you don't make a copy of the values in the array. `oldNumber` will point to the exact same array (and future changes in either variable reflect in the other).

You can make a copy with

```
oldNumber = Arrays.copyOf(number, number.length);
```

Answer (score 2):

In the putOld function you assigned the  *reference* of the first array to the other.  After the first call oldNumber is a pointer to number and if you change a value in one, the other one is affected too.

If you want to copy the values **System.arraycopy()**.